# Warn if async function is called without await

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way for Dart Analysis (or any other tool) to warn or even prevent the build if `await` was not used to while calling `async` function?

Comment: seems it is `unawaited_futures` - add it to `linter:
  rules:` in `analysis_options.yaml`

Comment: @pskink why are you answering the question in the comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Modify your `analysis_options.yaml` file](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) and enable the [`unawaited_futures`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) lint:

```yaml
linter:
  rules:
    - unawaited_futures
```

You can see a [full list of available lints](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/).

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me the correct syntax which worked for me was like this:
unawaited_futures: true

Comment: @hamidreza Either syntax is allowed.  See https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#individual-rules